# Imported he but node still says it is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I importing he into my project like so

`import * as he from 'he';`

I installed it by running

`npm install @types/he`

however when I attempt to run, however I get this error

`TypeError: he.decode is not a function`

the code I am using to test this is

`console.log(he.decode(animal_stuff))`

`

I am expecting to run he.decode and output a clean string.

Answer (score 2):

You just installed the Typescript definitions for the `he` package.

You should install the real library which can be found here:
[npmjs he](https://www.npmjs.com/package/he) and installed via:

```
npm install he
```